# Angular2 Form Validation scoping issue (Template Driven)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am unable to get the input in component2 to invalidate the form located in component1. The input that is in component1 invalidates the form fine. Is there anyway to invalidate a form using the inputs in child components in angular2? I would like to not have to propagate my form down through all the children and register the controls one by one

Component1:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-component1',
template: `
  <form #f="ngForm"> 
     <input name="value1" [(ngModel)]="value1" customvalidator>
     <app-component2></app-component2> 
     <input type="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">
  </form>`
})
export class Component1 {
}
```

Component2:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    template: '<input name="value2" [(ngModel)]="value2" customvalidator>'
})
export class Component2 {
}
```